# Is there an equivalent to TotalCmd?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there any alternative to [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) for linux?

Comment: also have a look at this question here http://askubuntu.com/questions/19459/which-norton-commander-style-filemanager-do-you-recommend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few alternatives:

- [Gnome Commander](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/gnome-commander)
- [Krusader](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/krusader) (although it requires KDE libs)
- [emelFm](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/emelfm2)
- [Midnight commander](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/mc) (runs in terminal)

Also, Nautilus - the file manager built into GNOME and thus Ubuntu - can show two panels in a window (press F3). Sometimes this is enough for some file copying.